# How to execute an external jar with classpath and also having CI argument using ant

Tags: java, jar, ant

I have a situation where I have a jar already with me. I do not need to create another jar using ant. Also, classpath should add as well.

**So my main goal is to run below command using ant**

Example is as below:

```
java -cp myjar.jar -DParameterA=A -DParameterB=B com.mypackagename.package.ClassName
```

---

I have refer below as well:

https://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/java.html

I am using command like:

```
 ant -Dcom.test=TEST1 targetName
```

In build.xml of ant I am trying something like below:

```
<target name="readclass">
    <java classname="${read-class}">
         <classpath>
           <pathelement location="myjar.jar"/>
         </classpath>
         <jvmarg value="-Xlingc"/>
         <arg value="${com.test}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```

But using my above code I am not able to pass arguments.
any suggestion would be helpful!!

Comment: you are passing arguments (`${arg0}` and `${arg1}`). I don't think I understand what you are asking.

Comment: @StefanBodewig  thanks for the reposnse , yes I have used the proper arguments as well like :  <arg value="${com.test}"/> as well , still getting nothing

Comment: so what is your question, then?

Comment: I am getting null .. so these arguments is not working

Comment: using command like : ant -Dcom.test=TEST1 targetName

Comment: you can run `ant -verbose` to see what Ant actually uses as command line arguments.

Comment: updated the xml and added the command in question .

Comment: with your updated question I would expect Ant to send the equivalent of `java -Xlingc -cp myjar.jar EXPANDED(read-secret) TEST1`. Is this not what you want?

Comment: `arg` is for everything after the class name, `jvmarg` for everything before the class name and if you want to set system properties (i.e. `-Dfoo=bar` before the class name) then you better use `sysproperty`.

Comment: also note, for jvmarg to have any effect you need to set `fork=true` as the default is to run the java class inside of the same VM that is running Ant.

Comment: Thanks a lot @StefanBodewig .. its working now :D ... Please add this as a answer .. I will accept it :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There are different kinds of arguments on the command line. The arguments that come before the class name are the arguments used and consumed by the JVM and you set them via `jvmarg` in Ant's `java` task. Arguments after the class name are sent to your class and you set them via `arg`.

A special case of `jvmarg` is the system property which is set via `-Dname=value` before the class name when you use the command line. Ant provides `sysproperty` for that.

`jvmarg`s require the task's `fork` attribute to be set to true as the default is to run the class in the same JVM that is executing Ant and thus the arguments to that have already been set. This does not apply to `sysproperty` which works with all `fork` settings.

If in doubt run `ant -verbose` which will provide you with the command line arguments Ant actually uses.

Comment: Hi @Stefan Bodewig , can we achieve the same thing using taskdef, if yes could you please give one example .. it will help

Comment: I think macrodef or presetdef would be the easiest way to wrap such a java task invocation into something reusable.

Comment: thanks, @Stefan Bodewig - for the insight

Answer (score 0):

Extended @Stefan Bodewig answer .. below is the ant block which works for me

```
<target name="readclass">
    <java classname="${read-class}" fork="true" failonerror="true">
         <classpath>
           <pathelement location="myjar.jar"/>
         </classpath>
         <sysproperty key="com.test" value="${com.test}"/>
         <sysproperty key="com.country" value="${com.country}"/>
    </java>
</target>
```